# Using methods from an outside class to get a specific variable from that method

Tags: java

I'm writing a wee text based questing game in Java to get the hang of the language a bit better.

I'm trying to create a method that can be called from another class. The method I want to call contains repeated variables and I want the correct variable to show up when I use a `switch` statement.

```
public class Enemies {

    String enemyName = "Generic Enemy";//initialised the enemy stats so something is called if the switch failed
    double enemyHealth = 110.0;
    int enemyAttackDamage = 10;
    int enemyDefenseLevel = 1;
    int hardLevel = 1;
    int lootDropped = 50;

    public void enemyDecided(int choice){
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: 
                this.enemyName = "Sentient Shoelace";
                this.enemyHealth = 100.0;
                this.enemyAttackDamage = 1;
                this.enemyDefenseLevel = 1;
                this.hardLevel = 2;
                this.lootDropped = 100;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.enemyName = "Slimey Fartbox";
                this.enemyHealth = 100.0;
                this.enemyAttackDamage = 2;
                this.enemyDefenseLevel = 1;
                this.hardLevel = 3;
                this.lootDropped = 100;
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Mess up in the enemy selection process");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call this from another class by

```
private void fight()
{
    //I'm using a rand.nextInt() to get enemychoice
    Enemies enemyToFight = new Enemies();
    enemy = enemyToFight.enemyDecided(enemyChoice);//
    System.out.println("You run into a "  + enemy.enemyName);
}
```

My `fight()` method doesn't work at all. And for good reason. What I have wrote is pure nonsense, though I'm at my wits' end and the edge of my meager knowledge.

I'm sure anyone with eyes can see that I'm trying to build a pseudo `struct`. As a recent convert from C, I'm still learning how to do things better. If this is all a terribly misguided idea to do in Java then could you point me in the right direction. Though a chance to save it would make me very happy indeed.

But I would like to try and get this working right if it's possible, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `enemy = enemyToFight.enemyDecided(enemyChoice);` You have a variable called `enemy` in your `fight()` method, but nowhere have you assigned it a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is a *constructor* for your `Enemies` class, rather than a `void` method:

```
public Enemies(int choice){
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: 
        this.enemyName = "Sentient Shoelace";
        this.enemyHealth = 100.0;
        this.enemyAttackDamage = 1;
        this.enemyDefenseLevel = 1;
        this.hardLevel = 2;
        this.lootDropped = 100;
        break;
    case 2:
        this.enemyName = "Slimey Fartbox";
        this.enemyHealth = 100.0;
        this.enemyAttackDamage = 2;
        this.enemyDefenseLevel = 1;
        this.hardLevel = 3;
        this.lootDropped = 100;
        break;
    default: System.out.println("Mess up in the enemy selection process");
    }
}
```

Now you can change your `fight()` method as follows:

```
private void fight()
{
    //I'm using a rand.nextInt() to get enemychoice
    Enemies enemy = new Enemies(enemyChoice);
    System.out.println("You run into a "  + enemy.enemyName);
}
```

There are still some stylistic issues you might like to ponder on:

1. You really want it to be called `Enemy` rather than `Enemies`.
2. You could think about using an `enum` if you just have two possibilities for an `Enemy`.
3. You might also think about having another constructor that takes six parameters, one for each thing you're setting. This could be a `private` constructor if you like, and that could be invoked by the `public` constructor that takes the `int choice`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very weird implementation, and very un-object oriented.

- You should have an `Enemy` class with the members that are currently in the `Enemies` class.
- Your `Enemies` class should contain a `List<Enemy>` variable, which contains an instance for each `Enemy`.

Then your `enemyDecided` method would be as simple as :

```
public Enemy enemyDecided(int choice) 
{
    return enemies.get(choice);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing return from a method that you are calling. So instead of

```
public void enemyDecided(int choice){
```

Use

public Enemies enemyDecided(int choice){

And at the end of the method add `return this;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to sure as to what you are having trouble with, but Ill give my thoughts anyway :)

In `Java`, plural class names are discouraged, so instead of `Enemies`, you would have a `Enemy` class with all the required attributes, and a controller to handle everything.

Here is something I created quickly to illustrate this idea in a more Object oriented fashion:

**Enemy**:

```
class Enemy {

    private final String enemyName;
    private final double enemyHealth;
    private final int enemyAttackDamage;
    private final int enemyDefenseLevel;
    private final int hardLevel;
    private final int lootDropped;

    public Enemy(String enemyName, double enemyHealth, int ad, int atd, int edl, int hl, int ld) {
        this.enemyName = enemyName;
        this.enemyHealth = enemyHealth;
        this.enemyAttackDamage = ad;
        this.enemyDefenseLevel = edl;
        this.hardLevel = hl;
        this.lootDropped = ld;
    }

    public String fight(final Player player) {
        // your fight method
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Player**:

```
class Player {
    // stub
}
```

**FightController**:

```
class FightController {

    private List<Enemy> enemies;
    private Player player;

    public FightController(List<Enemy> enemies, Player player) {
        this.enemies = enemies;
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void fight() {
        final int choice = 4;// decided by fair dice roll;
        if (choice >= 0 && choice < this.enemies.size()) {
            final Enemy toFight = this.enemies.get(choice);
            final String result = toFight.fight(player);

            // do somthing with result
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enemy first = new Enemy("One", 100d, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        Enemy second = new Enemy("second", 100d, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        Enemy third = new Enemy("third", 100d, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        Enemy fourth = new Enemy("fourth", 100d, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        Enemy fifth = new Enemy("fifth", 100d, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        new FightController(Arrays.asList(fifth, second, third, fourth, fifth), null/* your player*/).fight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `enemyDecided(int choise)` is void.
You can either:
(i) Make it return `this` and change the return type to `Enemies enemyDecided(int choice)`
OR
(ii) use only one variable in the `fight` method:

```
enemyToFight.enemyDecided(enemyChoice);
System.out.println("You run into a " + enemyToFight.enemyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Enemies enemyDecided(int choice){
switch(choice)
{
case 1: 
    this.enemyName = "Sentient Shoelace";
    this.enemyHealth = 100.0;
    this.enemyAttackDamage = 1;
    this.enemyDefenseLevel = 1;
    this.hardLevel = 2;
    this.lootDropped = 100;
    break;
case 2:
    this.enemyName = "Slimey Fartbox";
    this.enemyHealth = 100.0;
    this.enemyAttackDamage = 2;
    this.enemyDefenseLevel = 1;
    this.hardLevel = 3;
    this.lootDropped = 100;
    break;
default: System.out.println("Mess up in the enemy selection process");
}
return this;
```

}

```
Enemies enemy = enemyToFight.enemyDecided(enemyChoice);//
    System.out.println("You run into a "  + enemy.enemyName);
```